# IceFaces - commandButton doesn't return attatchment

Tags: java, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

CommandButton doesn't return attachment (txt file) from action. I have no errors. Just nothing happend.

**Java code:**

```
 FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
 response.setContentType("application/txt");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=file.txt");
 IOUtils.copy(new StringReader("TEST"), response.getOutputStream());
 facesContext.responseComplete();
 facesContext.renderResponse();
```

**iceFaces - jspx**

```
            <ice:commandButton 
                id="downloadBtn" 
                action="#{contentsBean.downloadAsZip}" 
                value="txt" partialSubmit="true" immediate = "true" >       
            </ice:commandButton>
```

I try to use commandButton, because i can't use ice:outputResource.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this JSF framework but commandButton works, in a wide way, as the traditional html button. Now pay attention to your code: you are invoking an action that sets some content in HttpServletResponse but what are you doing with this response? I believe nothing. What were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ice:outputResource as invisible button on website. When user will click commandButton you can induce something like "onClick" on ice:outputResource with using javaScript.